# CPQ How to Hide Preview Button

Tags: cpq, document, quote-template

Is there a way to hide the "Preview Button" while generating a document within CPQ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the preview button is included in a Visualforce page included in the CPQ Package.

Name of the page : SBQQ__GenerateWebDocument

Remove the line :

```
<button ng-click="onPreview()" class="sbBtn">{!$Label.lbl_preview}</button>
```

Not ideal but i am not aware of an click not code way to achieve this

Comment: I came to the same conclusion unfortunately, managed installed classes cannot be saved so if I tried to comment it out it wouldn't save. Thanks, I think it is just a button that will need to display.